# Is my model to big? I am trying to predict orders for a company, and I don't know if there are typical values for macroparameters

Tags: lstm, forecasting

I am building a model to predict orders, from its time series (univariate), for a company. I am working with 30 layers of 400 LSTM neurons each with the activation function hyperbolic tangent of Yann Lecun, 1 layer of 400 LSTM neurons with the relu activation function, and 3 layers of 500 neurons each, with a Relu Activation Function.

These values have had the best performance yet, but I don't know if there are typical values for training, or if it is an abnormally huge model.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, a model should be big enough to have a low bias (avoid underfitting), but not too big as to have too high of a variance (avoid overfitting), called the bias-variance tradeoff

[image]

Whether the bias is too low for you or not depends on the true distribution you are trying to model. Practically, this means whether your model is getting a low **training** loss or not.

Whether the bias is too high or not depends on the true distribution *and* how much data you have. If your model achieves low training loss but high **validation** loss, then it's overfitting and thus has too high of a variance. In that case you need to either lower the complexity of the model or get more data.

If you ever reach a point where

1- reducing the complexity of the model will make training loss too high, and

2- increasing the complexity of the model will make validation loss increase

Then the only way to improve is to either change your model architechture/hyperparameters in some way or get more data.